# How to create dynamic fields in Google App Engine expando class?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore, expando, dynamic-variables

I have a db expando class called widget.

I'm passing in a json string and converting it to a dict and then adding it to the datastore.

My question is how can I loop through my dict to create dynamic fields.

```
widget = Widget.get_by_key_name(key_name)
widget.name = self.request.get('wname')
fields = simplejson.loads(self.request.get('wcontents'))
for k,v in fields.iteritems():
  widget.k = v
```

This renders "k" as my field name as oppose to the k value in the dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `widget.k` references the attribute `k` on object `widget`.  To *dynamically* choose which attribute you set, use the built-in [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) method:

```
setattr(widget, k, v)
```

Dynamically setting an attribute like this will create the field on that particular entity.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
for k, v in fields.items()
```