# Datastore set property name from variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an unknown variable that I want to use as a datastore property name. I'm using Expando, as I know you can dynamically create properties without first declaring them in the db class, however I am unable to do this as the property names are not known. I get the error: 'StoreNames' object does not support item assignment. Is there any way around this?

```
class StoreNames(db.Expando):
  index = db.FloatProperty()

name = "unknown"

value = "something"

store = StoreNames()

store[name] = value
store.index = 0
```

Comment: Use the setattr() method as described here:  [How to create dynamic fields in Google App Engine expando class?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160752/how-to-create-dynamic-fields-in-google-app-engine-expando-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using the following code:

```
class StoreNames(db.Expando):
  index = db.FloatProperty()

name = "unknown"

value = "something"

store = StoreNames()

setattr(db, name, value)
```

I would have answered earlier but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me. Thanks Brent Washburne